# Swift KVO addObserver/observeValue for class objects

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I want to observe key value changes for a class var in Swift:

```
   AVCaptureDevice.observe(\.isCenterStageEnabled, options: [.new, .old]) { controller, value in
        NSLog("Value \(value)")
    }
```

But I get build errors:

```
 Instance member 'observe' cannot be used on type 'AVCaptureDevice'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

 Key path cannot refer to static member 'isCenterStageEnabled'
```

Obviously I can use the old KVO method *addObserver* and *removeObserver*, but right now I am trying to get rid of all such legacy methods slowly. What is the next best way to do KVO on class objects? I saw *observeValue* method but it's not clear how to use it in my context and if it is any better than legacy *addObserver* API?

Comment: I don't know how to use it, can you post an answer?

Comment: You seem to try to observe class instead of object of the class.

Comment: But this is what I am supposed to observe as per the API

Comment: Sorry @JoakimDanielson , I remove my comment

Comment: @DeepakSharma : you should create an AVCaptureDevice object (that will be the instance) and then apply the observe on it

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can add observer on class var as stated in the documentation :

> You can add property observers in the following places:
>
> - Stored properties that you define
> - Stored properties that you inherit
> - Computed properties that you inherit``